# Not able to match loginemail from neo 4j graph db

Tags: php, neo4j

My query is:

```
$email = $_POST['loginemail'];
$data1 = array(
"query" => "MATCH (a:userProfile { emailid: ".$email." }) RETURN a",
);
```

and query is responding like this:

```
array(4) {

    ["message"]=>
     string(350) "Invalid input '@': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property
      map, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', `'', "=", '=', "", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or '}' (line 1, column 38)
"MATCH (a:userProfile { emailid: test1@gmail.com }) RETURN a"`
```

then how can I match login email from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to put the value (aka the email address) in quotes, or much better, use parameterized cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html. To use parameters you need to check if your client driver supports them